# How to sort on a key located inside an array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I framed the following document structure after applying aggregation query on my mongodb collection of documents:

```
"lots": [
{
  "lot_no": "Lot number",
  "location": "ABC123",
  "shipping_line_id": "ONE1568295272",
  "shipping_line_name": "One Line",
  "containers": {
    "CNTR_20STD": {
      "qty": 10,
      "expiry_date": 87126348762
    },
    "CNTR_40STD": {
      "qty": 10,
      "expiry_date": 87126348762
    },
    "CNTR_40HC": {
      "qty": 20,
      "expiry_date": 87126348762
    }
  },
  "status": true,
  "lot_items": [
    {
      "_id": "String to be generated as ID",
      "origin_port": {
        "port_name": "Nhava Sheva",
        "port_code": "INNSA"
      },
      "destination_port": {
        "port_name": "Jebel Ali",
        "port_code": "AEJEA"
      },
      "container_type": "CNTR_20STD/CNTR_40STD/CNTR_40HC",
      "allowable_weight": 30,
      "special_terms": "Some special terms",
      "buy": 1000,
      "sell": 1200
    }
  ]
}
```

]

I want to be able to sort the results on the basis of origin port name/destintion port name/buy/sell/allowable weight, etc.

I am trying to do the following but, it is not working:
**{"$sort": {"lot_items.buy"}}**

Can someone help me as to how to sort according to the above-mentioned keys present in an array of objects in the MongoDB document?

Comment: hope you gave used the sort direction like: {
    "$sort": {
      "lot_items.buy": -1
    }
  }

Comment: If you want to sort the items in lot_items array, you need to `$unwind` that array, do the `$sort` and after that `$group` by document id,  to restore its structure, search for those its very common, you will find many examples(search how to sort nested array), read also mongodb documentation if needed, its very good and has examples.